# How to lose of weight fast relatively healthy

Tags: weight-loss, cardio

I'm 108 kg, around 25-28% bodyfat and I need to lose 18 kg in 2 month.

I know it's too fast, and it would be better to be on a caloric deficit while doing strength training + cardio for a longer period of time, but it is what it is.

What would be the healthiest way possible to do so? (keeping as much muscle as possible all other things being equal).

Should I do tons of cardio while being on caloric deficit?

I can track calories and do weightlifting cardio etc.

Comment: What is the reason you *need* to lose 18kg?

Answer (score 2):

#### You can’t.

I am sorry to inform you that your expectations are unrealistic. 18 kg lost in only two months at your body weight is extremely aggressive, and there is simply no way to do that without potentially serious risks to your health. Such aggressive weight loss should only be undertaken at the direction of, and under the supervision of, a doctor. Instead, I’d encourage you to aim for a more sustainable rate of weight loss, at most 1 kg a week (which is still aggressive, but not particularly risky), which will set you up to successfully keep the weight off.

Comment: yep, I already know it is too aggressive, to elaborate on my question, I already have experience losing around 5kg / month for 2-3 month with relatively low muscle loss.

The question is what would be the least unhealthy way to lose more than 8-10kg in 2 month (even if not 18kg precisely)

Comment: @Herokiller Yeah, 5kg a month is reasonable. You’re asking to double that. That is not safe. No one here is going to tell you how to do that because to do so would be to encourage potentially self-destructive behavior.

Comment: @Herokiller I think the only reasonable answer to the question of what the safest way to lose 5-10kg per month is would be "Under close medical or dietetic supervision."